# Best way to store and later use captions with Latex in Sweave?

Tags: r, text, latex, sweave

I would like to write figure captions in the R mode of Sweave and then, add the captions to a list, and later use them in a figure caption, for example:

```
caption <- list()
myresult <- data.frame(name = c('fee', 'fi'), x = c(1,2))
caption[['fig1']] <- "$\text{\Sexpr{myresult$name[1]}}\Sexpr{myresult$x[1]$" 
caption[['fig2']] <- "$\text{\Sexpr{myresult$name[2]}}\Sexpr{myresult$x[2]$"
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error: '\S' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "$\text{\S"
```

Is there a way that I can store such a string in a list, or a better approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Double-escape `\` characters. And you don't need double square brackets...

```
caption <- list()
myresult <- data.frame(name = c('fee', 'fi'), x = c(1,2))
caption['fig1'] <- "$\\text{\\Sexpr{myresult$name[1]}}\\Sexpr{myresult$x[1]$" 
caption['fig2'] <- "$\\text{\\Sexpr{myresult$name[2]}}\\Sexpr{myresult$x[2]$"
```

Frankly, I'd write a simple helper function:

```
genCaption <- function(name, value){
    sprintf("$\\text{%s}%.3f$", name, value)
}
```

and you'll get:

```
> genCaption("pi", pi)
[1] "$\text{pi}3.142$"
```

Comment: that answers my question ... I was focused on a way to do this givin the fact that I had already written out all of these strings, and wanted to wrap them in a function ... but I couldn't find one, except wrapping `gsub()` in a task-specific function.